# Метрический конвертер tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, конвертер

Почему когда я запускаю программу, она не может отобразить варианты систем, и так же не может вывести результат?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

length=["км", "дм", "см", "мм"]
speed=["км/ч", "км/мин", "м/ч", "м/мин"]


class ConverteruiApp:
 def __init__(self, master=None):
    # build ui
    self.mainwindow = ttk.Frame(master)
    self.title = tk.Label(self.mainwindow)
    self.title.configure(anchor='w', font='{gilroy} 16 {bold}', relief='flat', text='Конвертер')
    self.title.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.20', rely='0.03', x='0', y='0')


    value_type=tk.IntVar()
    self.radiobutton1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.mainwindow)
    self.radiobutton1.configure(value=1, variable=value_type, anchor='w', font='{gilroy medium} 12 {}', text='Длина')
    self.radiobutton1.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.12', rely='0.13', x='0', y='0')

    self.radiobutton2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.mainwindow)
    self.radiobutton2.configure(value=2, variable=value_type,  font='{gilroy medium} 12 {}', text='Время')
    self.radiobutton2.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.41', rely='0.13', x='0', y='0')

    self.radiobutton3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.mainwindow)
    self.radiobutton3.configure(value=3, variable=value_type,  anchor='w', font='{gilroy medium} 12 {}', text='Скорость')
    self.radiobutton3.place(anchor='n', relx='0.75', rely='0.13', x='0', y='0')
   
    self.label1 = tk.Label(self.mainwindow)
    self.label1.configure(compound='top', cursor='arrow', font='{gilroy} 12 {bold}', text='Перевести:')
    self.label1.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.13', rely='0.25', x='0', y='0')

    self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.mainwindow)
    self.entry1.configure(cursor='arrow', exportselection='true', font='{gilroy medium} 16 {}')
    self.entry1.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.13', rely='0.32', x='0', y='0')

    self.combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(self.mainwindow)
    self.combobox1.configure(cursor='hand2', width='45')
    self.combobox1.place(anchor='nw', relheight='0.05', relwidth='0.75', relx='0.13', rely='0.40', x='0', y='0')

    self.combobox2 = ttk.Combobox(self.mainwindow)
    self.combobox2.configure(cursor='hand2', width='45')
    self.combobox2.place(anchor='nw', relheight='0.05', relwidth='0.75', relx='0.13', rely='0.55', x='0', y='0')

    self.label2 = tk.Label(self.mainwindow)
    self.label2.configure(font='{gilroy} 12 {bold}', text='В:')
    self.label2.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.13', rely='0.48', x='0', y='0')

    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.mainwindow)
    self.button1.configure(anchor='n', cursor='hand2', font='{gilroy} 14 {bold}', text='Перевести')
    self.button1.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.32', rely='0.64', x='0', y='0')

    self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.mainwindow)
    self.entry2.configure(font='{gilroy light} 16 {bold}', state='readonly')
    _text_ = ''' '''
    self.entry2['state'] = 'normal'
    self.entry2.delete('0', 'end')
    self.entry2.insert('0', _text_)
    self.entry2['state'] = 'readonly'
    self.entry2.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.13', rely='0.81', x='0', y='0')

    self.label4 = tk.Label(self.mainwindow)
    self.label4.configure(font='{gilroy} 12 {bold}', text='Результат:')
    self.label4.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.13', rely='0.74', x='0', y='0')

    self.mainwindow.configure(height='540', padding='0', width='380')
    self.mainwindow.pack(side='top')

    # Main widget
    self.mainwindow = self.mainwindow


def select_value_type(self, *args):
    self.value_type = IntVar()
    self.value_type.trace_add('write', self.select_value_type)
    if value_type.get()==1:
        self.combobox1['values']=length
    elif value_type.get()==2:
        self.combobox1['values']=speed

def run(self):
    self.mainwindow.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = ConverteruiApp(root)
    app.run()
```

Comment: "и так же не может вывести результат?" - ну тут очевидно - потому что кнопка button1 ничего не делает

Answer (score 0):

Будем считать, что отступы случайно съехали при вставке кода.

Почему не заполняются комбобоксы в зависимости состояния переключателя - потому что привязка метода `select_value_type` к состоянию переменной переключателя находится в самом методе `select_value_type`, в итоге этот метод не вызывается никогда. Также `value_type` не нужно создавать заново в этом методе, а в методе `__init__` записать `value_type` как поле объекта, и потом в методе `select_value_type` через `self` к нему обращаться.

Кусок кода с изменениями:

```
class ConverteruiApp:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ...

        self.value_type=tk.IntVar()
        self.value_type.trace_add('write', self.select_value_type)
        
        self.radiobutton1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.mainwindow)
        self.radiobutton1.configure(value=1, variable=self.value_type, anchor='w', font='{gilroy medium} 12 {}', text='Длина')
        self.radiobutton1.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.12', rely='0.13', x='0', y='0')

        self.radiobutton2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.mainwindow)
        self.radiobutton2.configure(value=2, variable=self.value_type, font='{gilroy medium} 12 {}', text='Время')
        self.radiobutton2.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.41', rely='0.13', x='0', y='0')

        self.radiobutton3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.mainwindow)
        self.radiobutton3.configure(value=3, variable=self.value_type, anchor='w', font='{gilroy medium} 12 {}', text='Скорость')
        self.radiobutton3.place(anchor='n', relx='0.75', rely='0.13', x='0', y='0')

        ...


    def select_value_type(self, *args):
        if self.value_type.get()==1:
            self.combobox1['values']=length
            self.combobox2['values']=length
        elif self.value_type.get()==2:
            self.combobox1['values']=speed
            self.combobox2['values']=speed

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()
```